# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'firebaseConfig' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im getting error while connecting my html code to firebase database

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBSu7dx2w4GY6_HiPYyv0Gj_xDddoPa8hI",
    authDomain: "assistant2-139ff.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://assistant2-139ff-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "assistant2-139ff",
    storageBucket: "assistant2-139ff.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "888617709384",
    appId: "1:888617709384:web:a325963680f27cccea4d7d",
    measurementId: "G-W9NKQV6N45"
};

// Reference messages collection
var messagesRef  = firebase.database().ref('Login Details');

// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
    /* // Get values
    var name = getInputVal('fullname');
    var name = getInputVal('email');
    var password = getInputVal('password');
    
  
    // Save message
    saveMessage(fullname, email, password);*/ 
    
    console.log(123);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Apparently when I run firebase init hosting the firebase configuration is loaded in a init.js file and all runs without declaring it in my code